# Use calculus to determine the optimal levels of $L$ and $K$ that are required to maximize profit for this firm

Tags: calculus, economics

Stuck on this Economics question:

> Use calculus to determine the optimal levels of $L$ and $K$ that are required to maximize profit for this firm.

*Useful information:* A firm sells its output in a perfectly competitive market at a fixed price of $20$ per unit. It buys two inputs $L$ and $K$ at prices of $15$ and $50$ per unit respectively and has the following production function: $Q = 100\cdot L^{0.3}K^{0.5}$.

$\text{Profit} = 2000\cdot L^{0.3} K^{0.5} - 15L - 50K$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: is $Q$ given here?

Comment: Take partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$...

Answer (score 1):

This function$$f(L,K)=2000L^{0.3}K^{0.5}-15L-50K$$
has a maximum at the point $(L,K)$ where the gradient of the function is zero, i.e
$$\frac{\partial f(L,K)}{\partial L}=\frac{600\sqrt{k}}{L^{0.7}}-15=0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f(L,K)}{\partial K}=\frac{1000L^{0.3}}{\sqrt{k}}-50=0.$$
When you solve this system of equations, you get the answer
$$L=18 101933.59...$$
$$K=9050966.79...$$